# do while loop for text file not functioning

Tags: java, file, do-while

I need to read in a text file with an unknown number of questions. The formatting is always the same, but the number of options is not. I have taken care of this with a for loop.

If I remove the do while, the code successfully fetches one of the questions and stores it, but I need it to loop. The code won't even compile with the loop. I have tried many fixes, but it simply won't compile.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(f);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader =
        new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        String line;

            do {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                String question = line;

                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                int numoptions = Integer.parseInt(line);

                ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < numoptions; i++){
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    String choice = line;
                    options.add(choice);
                }

                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                int answer = Integer.parseInt(line);

                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                int tries = Integer.parseInt(line);

                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                int wins = Integer.parseInt(line);           

                Question objQ = new Question(question, numoptions, options,            answer, tries, wins); 
                mainlist.add(objQ);

            }   
            while (bufferedReader.readLine() != null);

                bufferedReader.close();
```

Comment: if it does not compile please provide the compiler error you get.

Comment: please provide the file you are reading with that loop.

Comment: Thanks to all who responded and gave advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while statement, you do a bufferedReader.readLine() from which you don't use the result. This is maybe not what you intented to do.

Please have a look at the code below, that should compile and read your questions text file (assuming this is one integer per line).

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ReadQuestions {

    static ArrayList<Question> mainlist = new ArrayList<>();


    static void readFile(File f) throws IOException {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(f);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        String line;


        while(true) {

            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            if(line == null)
                break;
            System.out.println(line);
            String question = line;

            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            int numoptions = Integer.parseInt(line);

            ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numoptions; i++) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                String choice = line;
                options.add(choice);
            }

            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            int answer = Integer.parseInt(line);

            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            int tries = Integer.parseInt(line);

            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            int wins = Integer.parseInt(line);


            Question objQ = new Question(question, numoptions, options,            answer, tries, wins);
            mainlist.add(objQ);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    }

    public static void main(String []arg) throws IOException {
        File f = new File("questions.txt");
        readFile(f);
    }


    public static class Question {
        public Question(String question, int numoptions, ArrayList<String> options, int answer, int tries, int wins) {
            // tbc
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: THAT is just what I needed, I knew my main formatting was right, but the loop parameter seemed funky. Thanks a bunch, man.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make a `while loop` instead of a `do ... while`. Then you should not make multiple `readLine` calls within the loop. For a start I would make it like this. I know this is not final 'cause I don't know what your file looks like.

```
String line = null;  
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
       String question = line;
       int numoptions = Integer.parseInt(line);

       ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
       for (int i = 0; i < numoptions; i++) {
            String choice = line;
            options.add(choice);
       }

       int answer = Integer.parseInt(line);
       int tries = Integer.parseInt(line);
       int wins = Integer.parseInt(line);           

       Question objQ = new Question(question, numoptions, options,  answer, tries, wins); 
       mainlist.add(objQ);
}
bufferedReader.close();
```

after looking at the file I might do it like this. I guess you now can complete it yourself:

```
int i = 0;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    i++;
    switch(i)
    {
       case 1: String question = line;
        break;

       case 2:
        int numoptions = Integer.parseInt(line);
        ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numoptions; i++) {
                String choice = line;
                options.add(choice);
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! But this throws a compilation error... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at assign3.Assign3.main(Assign3.java:46)
Java Result: 1

Comment: of course it does. in this code we try to cast EVERY line to `Int`. which will not work. I need to see your file in order to bring the `Integer.parseInt` in the right order.

Comment: I mean that it compiles fine without the loop enshrouding it. I tried the while loop before with my initial code and the same error was thrown :/

Comment: I don't know if it retains formatting...

Comment: nope. by coping it from the comment I loose the newlines. please provide is as a pastebin (http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xKwaP5PA

Comment: have a look at my answer. I guess you should get it that way.

Comment: Sorry, but your second code block smells really bad. You really want to use an int to decide how to handle a line of a file? And you really want to use another variable with the same name which has absolutely no chance to be compilable?

Comment: I don't understand why my initial code doesn't work. It reads the first section of text  file into the array perfectly, I just need it to repeat itself until the last line is reached.